# Error reading time stamp in a timer task

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I am reading time stamp data from a file, and these time stamps I woule like to use them later in a `Timer scheduler` to fire some events based on the time stamps. the time stamp format is some thing like this `0.012999999999` and they are of type string and i used `Long.parseLong` to convert it to `long`. I tried the below code but at run time i receive the below errors, it seems to me it is about the formating of the time stamp but i do not know how to handle it.

**code**:

```
    static TimerTask timedTask = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(timedTask, Long.parseLong(logfile.getFileHash().get(1).getTimeStamp()));
```

**errors**:

```
Exception in thread "file processing" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:   
"0.012999999999"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
at com.example.File_IO_00.File_IO.processFile(File_IO.java:77)
at com.example.File_IO_00.File_IO.access$1(File_IO.java:69)
at com.example.File_IO_00.File_IO$1.run(File_IO.java:20)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: where is the time stamp format from

Answer (score 0):

`Long` is an integer type, i.e. 0.012999999999 is not a valid value. you should use `Float.parseFloat()` or `Double.parseDouble()` instead.

Comment: ok but now, the timer task taks Long parameter as a second argument?

Comment: You can round it to a Long value using `Math.round(Double.parseDouble(..))`. However, that is most likely not what you want, since it would give you 0 for the string you provided. Most likely, the timestamp string is in seconds, Timer takes a value in milliseconds, so you can to convert it using `Math.round(1000 * Double.parseDouble(..))`.